# get the time under ubuntu storage size

Tags: c, time

I'm writing a program in C-language which its a simulation program for one barbershop one chair model under Ubuntu 13.04 environment .

I have a timer () function which gives me this error :

`storage size of ‘t’ isn’t known>>`

here is the function and the instruction which call it :

```
  #include<time.h>
  #include<math.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>
```

the function :

```
 long timer()
 {
     //get current system time
     struct time t;

     gettime(&t);
     //return number of hundred of second
     return(((long)3600*t.ti_hour+60*t.ti_min+t.ti_sec)*100+t.ti_hund);
 }
```

the instruction which call this function :

```
 srand((unsigned) timer());
```

may questions are :

1- what that's error main ?

2-how can I fix this error ?

Comment: Read *carefully* [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html), [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html), [localtime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html), [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html), [random(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html) ... There is no standard `struct time` !

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to run MS-DOS / Turbo-C code on Linux?

There's no `struct time` and `gettime()` function in the Unix C library, you're probably looking for `struct tm` and `localtime()` instead, see e.g.:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_localtime.htm

Comment: i ran this program under windows 7 
i used dos.h 
also the same problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are on ubuntu, you can just do:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

You don't need your own `timer()` function.  If you need more fine resolution than 1 second, look into `gettimeofday`.