# timer routine facing storage error

Tags: c, time

Im building a simulation project using queue event driven algorithm . its a sleeping barbershop queuing simulation model.

Im preparing a timer routine which uses to get the seed value to initialize the random number.

Timer routine uses to get the seed value and returns a number of hundred-second from

midnight until now.

```
 C Code:

     long timer()
       {
       //get current system time

         struct time t;
         gettime(&t);

       //return number of hundred of second
         return(((long)3600*t.ti_hour+60*t.ti_min+t.ti_sec)*100+t.ti_hund);
        }
```

the problem is that (storage size of "t" is not knowm)

this problem has found on both ubuntu 13.04 and windows 8 after i ran the code on both OS enviroment .

my questions :
1- what is that error , I need an explanation .
2- how can I fix this  error and return the same  number of hundred-second from midnight until now.

note :I read that gettime is not at linux os;

Comment: Is this supposed to be written using some textbook library or something? Standard C doesn't have `struct time` with `ti_hour` etc., or `gettime`, but it does have `struct tm` with `tm_hour` etc., and `localtime`.

Comment: Didn't you already [ask this question and get the same answers here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334142/get-the-time-under-ubuntu-storage-size)

Comment: i read that  the "dos.h" do that  >
but I have included it to the code and the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because your compiler is not able to find the definition of `struct time` which is not a *standard* data type and that's why it complains that it cannot create a variable of some data type for which the size is not known.

I am not aware of how you need to do it on windows, but on linux, your purpose can be achieved by using

1. `struct timeval` variable, which is defined as below.
2. `gettimeofday()` function.

*The structure:*

```
struct timeval {
    time_t      tv_sec;     /* seconds since Jan. 1, 1970 */
    suseconds_t tv_usec;    /* microseconds */
};
```

*The function:*

```
int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz);
```

chek the man page [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html) for more details.

Note : You need to add `#include <sys/time.h>` to your code.

Comment: Or simpy `<time.h>` on windows.

Comment: @Zaibis thanks for mentioning that. :-)

Comment: thanx . but i need the same return value as that function returns ^_^